# How do control bootstrap open popup behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-plugins

```
 <a href="#open-popup" data-href="#open-popup" class="open-popup" id="open-popup-button">open PopUp</a>
```

It opens full-screen popup , now i want to check some condition before opening popup.

```
 if(conditionMet){
   // Open popup
 }else{
   //show msg
   }
```

I tried so far

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-href="#open-popup" class="open-popup" id="open-popup-button">open PopUp</a>
 if(conditionMet){
 $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('data-href'))
}else{
 //show msg
}
```

But it is not working.I am using jquery fullscreen popup.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-href="open-popup" class="open-popup" id="open-popup-button">open PopUp</a>

 $(document).on('click','a#open-popup-button', function(e){
   if(conditionMet){
     $(this).attr('href',`#${$(this).attr('data-href')}`)
   }else{
     //show msg
   }
   e.preventDefault();
 });
```

I've removed `#` from `data-href` so that your library can't target the element & attached a `click` event.

In that click event, you can check the condition & based on the condition you can open up the popup.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: $(this).attr('href',`#${$(this).attr('data-href')}`) will works ?

Comment: @manikantgautam Yes it will work, I've used `ES6` template literals. Have a check https://jsfiddle.net/gLycd78z/

Comment: have u checked fiddle ? it isn't working over there . correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @manikantgautam You should check in the browser inspect section in browser console panel. I've edited the jsfiddle, after the href updates it will console log for you https://jsfiddle.net/gLycd78z/1/